# Popup window for giving information about products

Tags: css, popup

I wish to have a question mark beside the important options of my website, so that I can show the users information about that option right there in a small popup window.

I wish to have a popup window like [this](http://uk.madbid.com/future). Click on the Set Reminder option to see the popup. Can anyone guide me how they have made this or what have they used, for this nice little popup box.

Thanks :)

Comment: I was using another plugin that comes at first visit on this site. http://buyhatke.com But I cant block the display on every click, will look ODD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it a tooltip. There are tons of tools which can help you achieve that effect. Depending on your preferred javascript framework, you can find many plugins. Here are a few for the jQuery framework.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/

If you want more, you can google "jQuery tooltips".

P.S: If you want the tooltips to appear on a "click" event, play around with the javascript file of the tooltip you select.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function showpopup(id) {
d = document.createElement('div');
d.style.position = 'absolute';
d.style.height = '100px';
d.style.width = '100px';
d.innerHTML = '<p>Testing...</p>';
d.setAttribute('style', d.getAttribute('style') + 'background-color: blue;');
d.style.top = '' + (document.getElementById(id).style.top - 100);
d.style.left = '' + (document.getElementById(id).style.left - 50);
document.body.appendChild(d);
}
</script>
<a href='#' id='l1' onclick='showpopup("l1");'>aalsdkfj</a>
```

Comment: I updated the code, so the box has a blue background now. Does it work? If not, what browser are you using? Is your browser up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tools you could use, including a hundred modal dialogs for jQuery. If you want a comprehensive solution that doesn't depend on a CSS framework, take a look at [Floatbox](http://floatboxjs.com/). It's relatively slim, easy to work with and support is great.